# Kotlin syntax: Difference between using the class name instead of the companion object name

Tags: kotlin, ktor

Looking at this code that imitates how [features](https://ktor.io/servers/features.html#installing) are installed in [Ktor](https://ktor.io/) applications.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    val app = App()
    app.installFeature(Authentication)
}

interface AppFeature {
    fun install()
}

class Authentication {

    companion object Feature : AppFeature {
        override fun install() = println("Authentication Installed")
    }
}

class App {

    fun installFeature(appFeature: AppFeature) {
        println("Installing appFeature `${appFeature::class.simpleName}`")
        appFeature.install()
    }
}
```

What doesn't make sense to me in the above snippet is this line `app.installFeature(Authentication)`

Can anyone explain to me why using the `class` name instead of the `companion object` name works just like the more obvious way `app.installFeature(Authentication.Feature)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/object-declarations.html#companion-objects):

> Members of the companion object can be called by using simply the class name as the qualifier

And similarly, you can use `Authentication` as an `AppFeature` directly.